# Move exchange mailboxes cross forest

Tags: email, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, migration, mailbox

Having a hard time migrating user mailboxes across 2 forests.
I've set up ADMT 3.2, No dns issues and fully route-able between the domains etc.

Have come to migrate user mailboxes and the exchange shell just comes back with ...

> [PS] C:>New-MoveRequest -Identity "username" -TargetDatabase "maildb"
>   -RemoteGlobalCatalog 'gdc.doman.local' -RemoteCredential (get-credential)
>   -TargetDeliveryDomain 'sourcedomain.local'
>
> Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-MoveRequest], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,New-MoveRequest

We are running a mixed environment (windows server 2003 and up with exchange 2003 and exchange 2010 (different servers obviously)) as a source domain and full Server 2008 R2 servers in the target domain with only 1 exchange 2010 server.

We have ran this command on the Exchange 2010 server on the target domain and when asked giving the credentials of an admin in source domain in the format : sourcedomain\source_administrator

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Rhys

Comment: You may find value in reading my answer to a similar question a few months ago: http://serverfault.com/questions/202743/migrating-mailstore-from-exchange-2003-to-exchange-2010-in-a-new-domain/208153#208153

Answer (score 1):

Try this command instead:

```
New-MoveRequest –Identity "Email Address" –RemoteLegacy –RemoteGlobalCatalog "OLD PDC FQDN" –TargetDeliveryDomain "DomainName.Local" –TargetDatabase "Database" -RemoteCredential $RemoteCredentials
```

Also on the old domain make sure in ADSI edit that under legecyExchangeDN the value `/o=First Organization/ou=First Administrative Group/cn=Recipients/cn=aliasname` is set.